# Set Hidden Input Value with Ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I did quite a lot of research and tried many offered solutions, but so far nothing worked or fitted my needs, so I decided to ask the question myself

I want to set the value of two hidden input fields using the response of an AJAX request consuming a webservice

The Webservice returns a single JSON formatted object like this

```
{"id":"1-3","invoiceId":"123","companyId":"1","pointsAwarded":0,"rated":false}
```

Appending the invoiceId works but the values of the inputs remain empty

This is the JS Script i use right now

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $.ajax({url: "http://localhost:8080/companies-1/nextRating"})

       .then(function(data) {
        $('.invoiceId').append(data.invoiceId);

        $("#invoiceId").val(data.invoiceId);
        $("#companyId").val(data.companyId);
    });
})
```

What am I missing??

---

**EDIT:**

This is where the class selector appends the data

```
<p class="invoiceId">This Rating is valid for Nr.</p>
```

And this is where the id selector should inject the information

```
<input name="invoiceId" id = "invoiceId" type="hidden">
<input name="companyId" id = "companyId" type="hidden">
```

---

**SOLUTION:**

Changed the ID to `invoice`, because I named the `class` and `id` the same, my bad

Thanks for the advice

Comment: What you have should work fine. We need to see your HTML to help you. Do you have multiple elements with the same `id` attributes?

Comment: You use `.invoiceId` (a class selector) in one place, and `#invoiceId` (an id selector) later. Is that on purpose?

Comment: Is the invoiceId actually appending to the class 'invoiceId' or is that just what you expect?

Comment: do come success ajax  script

Comment: Is there any error in console?

Comment: No the Id and Class were named the same, thats why it didnt worked

Comment: @crunpy There is no problem with the same class name and ID. The code which you provided is absolutely working. Please check again the hidden value by inspecting that element.

Answer (score -1):

With jQuery

```
$('selector').val(value)
```

should work, but like Rory said we need your HTML to help more.